# How to make my GPT bot answer questions using the data from a database?

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api, langchain

I am researching on how to create a chatbot that provides information to the user from the APIs or databases, and not some document.

I watched a couple of videos on Youtube over langchain and GPT bots.

Here is what I gathered:

GPT bots need prompts. They need a dataset from where they can answer questions.

What I need:

1. My GPT bot should be domain specific, i.e., refuse to answer any other kinds of questions.
2. Extract the intent, the data provided in the user input.
3. Make an API call (I will provide the API endpoints, user, password) to the respective URL with the data in the query parameters
4. Once it gets the data from the API, it should respond with the data it retrieved.

In a nutshell, I don't need the bot to train on some document, I just need the GPT API to understand the intent from the user input, and carry on a conversation. I just need it to fetch the data dynamically from the database/APIs.

------EXAMPLE------
INPUT - Tell me which orders did I receive yesterday?

Intent - fetch orders
Data - from yesterday

Webservice call - [www.example.com/orders?dateStart=${YESTERDAY}&dateToday=${TODAY}](http://www.example.com/orders?dateStart=$%7BYESTERDAY%7D&dateToday=$%7BTODAY%7D)

ANSWER - Here are the list of orders:-

1. ABCD - qty 1
2. EFGH - qty 10

--------EXAMPLE---------

Earlier I thought I could leverage langchain for this, but I'm not sure. And also confused on how to search the internet for my requirement. I really need guidance.

It could be possible that I am looking at the wrong technology for this. If not this, then what?

Many thanks!

Comment: Ask ChatGPT... Use of ChatGPT or AI is not on topic here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. So this is not the right place to ask this question?

Comment: I actually want to use the Open AI API to create a chatbot.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr;
https://cookbook.openai.com/examples/how_to_call_functions_with_chat_models
OR
https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/how-it-works

Some time ago you needed to play with prompt to make ChatGPT identify and send you back function calls (example later). Right now it's embedded in the API. You still need to send 2 calls (once to identify functions and another with the additional information) but it's much more formal, stable and easier.

There are 2 approaches - tools list where you define ChatGPT which "tools" (former "function_calls") you have and it will respond with list of tools it needs to call and how. And Assistants which can be pre-created and configured with available functions so that you don't need to repeat it on each future request. So best is follow examples and documentation of OpenAI itself.

Here's how function calls were done before the "tools" API parameter. You first send request with prompt similar to this:

```
Here is a list of available functions:
get_price(symbol) - receives stock symbol returns last price as number
get_title(symbol) - receives stock symbol returns title as string
get_num_shares(symbol) - receives stock symbol number of shares as number

List function calls that will help answering my question in JSON array. Answer with JSON only, without explanations. Example:
[ {"function": "get_price"}, {"arguments": ["XOM"]} ]

Question:
What is the latest price and title of MSFT?
```

Parse results, call functions, send another prompt:

```
You have the following information:
price of MSFT is $377.43
title of MSFT is  "Microsoft Corporation Common Stock"

Please answer the question while using the above information to fill the gap in knowledge:
What is the latest price and title of MSFT?
```

You can paste this in ChatGPT and see the answers. Play with question and examples, sometimes it can glitch.
However, as of recently Assistant API supposed to replace all that, so go to
https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/how-it-works
and learn how to use it.